# How to connect my External SATA Hard Drive Case to the network ( / to the router )

Tags: networking, hard-drive

I have some external SATA hard drive cases (with hard drives inside).  I want these hard drives to be shared in all of my network.  To do this I need to make some connection between the external SATA hard drive case and the network router.

Is there some way of accomplishing this or some hardware that can be help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have SATA - USB adapters available, if your router has a USB port and supports some sort of Network Attached Storage (NAS) configuration, thats one possibility i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

not really a question for stackoverflow, but you could use a [pogoplug](https://pogoplug.com/devices)

Comment: sorry - i really don't know where else can i publish this question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your budget you could get a dedicated NAS to put your drives in. They would generally give you much better access speeds than connecting them via USB.

If you're in the UK something like http://www.ebuyer.com/611614-zyxel-nsa310s-diskless-media-server-nsa310s-gb0101f would work.